# Mysql, show results with a Timediff on more then 2 min

Tags: mysql

I like to only show result with TIMEDIFF on MORE then 2 min

Table:

```
dt                   session_id
2016-11-15 11:25:00  1
2016-11-15 11:21:04  1
2016-11-15 11:20:00  1
2016-11-15 09:37:00  2
2016-11-15 09:27:00  2
2016-11-14 21:37:00  3
2016-11-14 21:33:35  3
2016-11-14 21:31:00  3
2016-11-14 16:05:00  4
2016-11-14 16:04:35  4
2016-11-14 10:31:25  5
2016-11-14 10:31:00  5
```

My query:

```
SELECT 

    MIN(dt) Start,
    MAX(dt) End,
    TIMEDIFF(MAX(dt),MIN(dt)) as sessionTime,

FROM table
WHERE sessionTime > "00:02:00"
GROUP BY session_id
```

This query do not giv any results.

This is how I like the results:

```
Start                 End                   sessionTime
2016-11-15 11:20:00   2016-11-15 11:25:00   00:05:00
2016-11-15 09:27:00   2016-11-15 09:37:00   00:10:00
2016-11-14 21:31:00   2016-11-14 21:37:00   00:06:00
```

Comment: This query would error out. So I'm confused

Comment: `2016-11-15 11:20:00   ` is not there in your input.

Comment: Updated the input.

Comment: @SalmanA No it was an other question

Comment: Try changing `WHERE TIMEDIFF...` to `HAVING TIMEDIFF...`. I think that is it.

Comment: @Strawberry You are KING!! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT session_id

    MIN(dt) Start,
    MAX(dt) End,
    TIMEDIFF(MAX(dt),MIN(dt)) as sessionTime

FROM table
GROUP BY session_id
Having sessionTime > "00:02:00"
```

Comment: I like the sessionTime to be more then 2 min. Is there any way to do that?